# Помогите описать дату в запросе

Tags: sql

Есть таблица, из которой нужно выбрать заявки, поступившие с 20.00 до 08.00, сделать это нужно за месяц к примеру. Как описать дату в этом случае?

Запрос:

```
Select Номер заявки
From Таблица
Where Условия
and Условия
and время поступления заявки = 01.01.2016 - 02.01.2016 
                               hh24:mi:ss - 20.00.00 - 08:00:00
```

**Обновление**

Вот такие записи даты сейчас:

```
to_char(datestamp,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and CAST(TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')+((act1.a3)/86400+4/24)AS TIMESTAMP)  >= to_date('01.03.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')
and CAST(TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')+((act1.a3)/86400+4/24)AS TIMESTAMP)  <= to_date('01.04.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: Время и дата хранятся в разных полях?

Answer (score 3):

В диалекте postgresql

```
SELECT date_part('hour', calltime) as CallHour
FROM table
WHERE date_part('hour', calltime)<8 OR date_part('hour', calltime)>20
```

Для других диалектов может называться datepart.

И совсем клинический случай - преобразовать в строку формата "HH" (взять только часы) и работать с ней.

Comment: Спасибо @betonimig за проверку и правку

Comment: А можете для чайничка расписать)